# $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation with $T^2=T$. Proof of the statements.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation that satisfies $T^2=T$.

a) How to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$?

b) How to prove that $x - T(x) \in Ker(T)$?

c) How to prove that $V = Ker(T) \oplus Im(T)$?

Comment: could you please show us your own effort?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You might start with one of the related questions listed at right, such as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290771/265466.

Comment: All of these questions have numerous solutions on the site. Even if you're unwilling to post your own work, you should not be so remiss as to look for things that are already there. If you are unwilling to do even that then I don't think anyone will have much sympathy for your questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:**

$$T(u)=\lambda u \Rightarrow T^2(u)=\lambda^2 u$$

Now use $T^2=T$.

**Hint 2:**

$$T(x-T(x))=...$$

**Hint 3**
$$x=(x-T(x))+T(x)$$